# Show plot outline, border

Tags: r, shiny, vis.js, visnetwork

Using *visNetwork* package, how can we add border?

**Reference:** [GitHub](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork), [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=visNetwork) and [Online documentation](http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/)

```
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                    color.background = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                    color.highlight.background = c("red", NA, "red"), 
                    shadow.size = c(5, 10, 15))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3),
                    label = LETTERS[1:2], 
                    font.color =c ("red", "blue"), 
                    font.size = c(10,20))

visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```

We could set the background colour, but I would prefer just the outline/border of the plot.

---

In case it is relevant, I am using this within *shiny*, here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    visNetworkOutput("vis1", height = "200px"),
    visNetworkOutput("vis2", height = "200px")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, group = c("B", "A", "B"))
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

    output$vis1 <- renderVisNetwork({
      visNetwork(nodes, edges,
                 main = "my vis 1")
      })
    output$vis2 <- renderVisNetwork({
      visNetwork(nodes, edges, background = "red",
                 main = "my vis 2, with red background")
    })

  })
```

And would like to see the outline of the plot, here first vis (`vis1`) has no outline, just transparent background, it is hard to tell where the borders are:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could opt for a CSS solution as this context is shiny specific.

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      #vis1 {
                        border: 2px solid black;
                      }
                      "))
      ),

    visNetworkOutput("vis1", height = "200px"),
    visNetworkOutput("vis2", height = "200px")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, group = c("B", "A", "B"))
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

    output$vis1 <- renderVisNetwork({
      visNetwork(nodes, edges,
                 main = "my vis 1")
    })
    output$vis2 <- renderVisNetwork({
      visNetwork(nodes, edges, background = "red",
                 main = "my vis 2, with red background")
    })

  })
```

I also recommend putting the CSS in its own stylesheet.
Refer to [this guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) for how that can be done.

Comment: Thank you that is great for shiny environment usage, I wish this was just part of `visNetwork`.